# Django string model reference for through field keyword argument

Tags: python, django

This is working for me:

```
class Task(models.Model):
     many_dateranges = models.ManyToManyField('DateRange')

class DateRange(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    task_myset = models.ManyToManyField(Task, through=Task.many_dateranges.through)
```

I wanted to have a reverse relation that is explicit in the code for some reasons, and its ok.

But in case of circular imports, it fails for string model reference:

```
class DateRange(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    task_myset = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Task', through='myapp.Task.many_dateranges.through', blank=True)

class Task(models.Model):
     many_dateranges = models.ManyToManyField(DateRange)
```

I get this error, even if i specify the app name or not:

```
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'myapp.Task.many_dateranges.through'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just need to input the intermediary model name, here `myapp.Task_many_dateranges`

```
class DateRange(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    task_myset = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Task', through='myapp.Task_many_dateranges', blank=True)

class Task(models.Model):
     many_dateranges = models.ManyToManyField(DateRange)
```

You can now the intermediary model name with a print of the field's through attribute:

```
instance = Task.objects.first()
print(instance.many_dateranges.through)
#  <class 'myapp.models.Task_many_dateranges'>
```

Comment: Same problem here, have you solved ?

Comment: i guess, it's in the answer, `'myapp.Task_many_dateranges'` instead of `'myapp.Task.many_dateranges.through'`